# What is the code not letting me add item to inventory?

Tags: python

```
character_name = "John Wick"

character_age = "45"

character_location = "California"

character_inventory = ()

print("There was once a man named " + character_name + "." "He was put in prison for life when he was " +
      character_age + " for killing a man in " + character_location + ", and after lying to the police about it.")
print("When " + character_name + " turned 50, he decided that his life was not going to improve.") 

while True:
        
    Action = input("You see a pistol.(Pick up)")
    
    if Action == "Pick up":
            
    character_inventory.append("Pistol")
            
    print(character_inventory)
            
    print("A pistol has been added to your inventory")
```

Comment: tuples are immutable, use a list instead

Comment: Thank you for contributing to StackOverflow.  When asking questions, it is best to provide a minimal working example and to provide the expected and observed behavior to help others in answering your questions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more recommendations.

Comment: Please mark your question's code parts as 'code'

Answer (score 0):

You can't append an element to a tuple, instead make it a list.

```
character_name = "John Wick"

character_age = "45"

character_location = "California"

character_inventory = []

print("There was once a man named " + character_name + "." "He was put in prison for life when he was " + character_age + " for killing a man in " + character_location + ", and after lying to the police about it.") 
print("When " + character_name + " turned 50, he decided that his life was not going to improve.")

while True:

   Action = input("You see a pistol.(Pick up)")

   if Action == "Pick up":

      character_inventory.append("Pistol")

      print(character_inventory)

      print("A pistol has been added to your inventory")
```